# How can I access to value inside a function JS + Cypher

Tags: javascript, function, scope, cypher

This is a query with de Neo4j js driver. The query works fine, and I can get the value in the `var x`. But the value only can be access inside the function g. If I try to call the function I have a message that said that g is no defined. (thank you for your help)

```
session
    .run( "MATCH (a:Autor) RETURN a.nombre AS name") 
    .then( 
        function g( result ) { 
            var x=result.records[0].get("name");//ok, x take the value
            console.log('es '+x); //ok, print the first value of the db
            session.close();
            return x;
        });
var r=g(); //error Uncaught ReferenceError: g is not defined
console.log('es '+r); //do not execute this part
```

Comment: `g` is the name of your promise callback. What value did you even expect to get when calling that without a `result` (if we ignore for a moment that `g` is not in scope)?

Comment: I was expecting the value of x. I think that I am not understanding how the session object works, If you have some references, It would be great.

Comment: `run()` obviously returns a promise, which means that you can only get the value `x` **asynchronously** in a callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
var result = session
.run( "MATCH (a:Autor) RETURN a.nombre AS name") 
.then( 
    function g( result ) { 
        var x=result.records[0].get("name");//ok, x take the value
        console.log('es '+x); //ok, print the first value of the db
        session.close();
        return x;
    });
```

Now to get the result anywhere, simply do this :

```
result.then( function (data) { console.log('es' + data) });
```

Comment: Thank you, but is it posible to storage the value in a variable, for just call it? for example  with document.write('<h1>'+result+'</h1');

Comment: I solve it using:  result.then( function (data) {document.getElementById("titulos").innerHTML=data;});

Comment: assign it to a global variable and watch for it to change value. Usually it is recommended to use a framework who gives you inbuild watchers' access